# Formula that calculates price after percentage discount, but needs to ignore a "-" to show no discount =IF(I40<>"-",(I39-(I39*I40)))

Tags: formulas

So I have a formula for adding subtotal after a percentage discount is taken off.
(I39-(I39*I40)

I also have a dropdown list for percentages so 10% 15% 20% and none labeled as -

This is what I have  `=IF(I40<>"-",(I39-(I39*I40)))`

The problem with this is that the formula comes back as False when - is chosen
I need it to calculate the percentage off, when there is one (10%), and show the total when there isn't one (-).

Comment: Is this an Excel question or a Google Sheets question? They are not the same. Please remove whichever tag does not apply to your actual situation.

Comment: This question was bumped by Community User. Questions about spreadsheet formulas in general are better suited for [so]. Here questions should be about using a specific Web application. If you need that the formula be compatible between multiple apps, this should be specified.

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign a value/formula to be used when the result is "-"

Try this:

`=IF(I40<>"-",(I39-(I39*I40)),I39)`

- `I40<>"-"` generates a "true"/"false"

  - true = `(I39-(I39*I40))`
  - false - `I39`